# Returning the array in an array of arrays with a value from another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have and array of arrays aa = [['a'], ['b'], ['c']] and i have an array a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
I need to get the item in aa for each element in a i.e i want to list elements in a with their respective arrays in aa the result should be like
a: ['a'] b: ['b'] c: ['c']
I tried this code but it does return the first element i aa for each element in a

I wonder what's wrong here

```js
const aa = [
  ['a'],
  ['b'],
  ['c']
]
const a = ['a', 'b', 'c']

let b = []
a.forEach((el) => {
  b.push(
    aa.filter((element) => {
      return element.includes(el)
    })
  )
})
console.log(b)
```

Comment: can you add the result in literal notation?

Comment: I think my problem is how i handle the result. Thanks Nina and mplungjan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```js
const aa = [
  ['a'],
  ['b'],
  ['c']
];
const a = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
let b = {};
a.forEach( // loop "a"
  aEl => b[aEl] = aa.filter(   // filter "aa" 
    aaEl => aaEl.includes(aEl) // on array that includes the item from 'a'
  ).flat() // we need to flatten the resulting array before returning it
);
console.log(JSON.stringify(b)); // using stringify to make it readable
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you want your output to be a key-value list (`a: ['a']`), variable `b` should be a map. Let's also rename `b` to `out` for readability.

```
out = {}
```

To get a better view of if our code is working, let's use some unique test data, and let's rename `a` to `keys` and `aa` to `values`.

```
const keys = ['A', 'B', 'C']

const values = [
      ['A', 'A2', 'a3'],
      ['B1', 'B', 'b3'],
      ['C1', 'C2', 'C']
    ]
```

For every key in `keys`, we want to set search for all arrays in `values` that contain the key. To set the search result to `out` we use brackets like so:

```
keys.forEach((key) => {
    out[key] = values.filter(valueArr => valueArr.includes(key))
})
```

This outputs:

```
{
  "A": [["A", "A2", "a3"]],
  "B": [["B1", "B", "b3"]],
  "C": [["C1", "C2", "C"]]
}
```

Now there are two arrays around each value. This is because `values.filter` can return multiple arrays. To combine these into a single array you can use the [flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) function. The whole code looks like:

```js
const keys = ['A', 'B', 'C']

const values = [
  ['A', 'A2', 'a3'],
  ['B1', 'B', 'b3'],
  ['C1', 'C2', 'C']
]
out = {}
keys.forEach((key) => {
    out[key] = values.filter(valueArr => valueArr.includes(key)).flat()
})

console.log(out)
```